# Stucked in world texture panel

Tags: interface

I'm learning blender and I want to apply an uv map.

I'm blocked because my texture panel is blocked for the world but I have selected an other object (I'm in object mode)

You can see my panel below. The picture is the picture of my world outside.

Any idea?

My current panel
[image: panel]

My wanted panel
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in **cycles** render engine. The texture panel, and material panel are different in cycles than in *Blender internal*.

What you want, is the texture panel from **Blender internal**.

I'm sorry, but there's not way to get the Blender internal panel in cycles, and it would not be practical, as the renderers work in different ways. You could switch to Blender Internal, but Cycles has many superiorities, so if I were you, I would just use the new design, and get used to the way it works.

Keep in mind: You can switch which texture you are editing in Cycles, by clicking where it says "environment texture", and selecting another texture.